# Jquery how to get index from input name attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have this code which works ok, but i was wondering if it could be done faster with jquery to get the index from input name attribute

```
<input name="inp[myindex]" value="bla" />
```

and the jquery

```
var $idx = $this.attr('name');
var $split = $idx.split('[');
$idx = $split[1];
$idx = $idx.replace(']', '');
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

A concise idiom to extract a string between two boundaries is split-pop-shift:

```
var subname= this.name.split('[').pop().split(']').shift();
```

or there's always the regex method, shorter still though ugly:

```
var subname= this.name.match(/\[([^[]*)\]/)[1];
```

jQuery is focused on DOM manipulations and doesn't have its own string processing functions to speak of. The method of using square brackets for indexed field names is a PHP quirk rather than anything inherent to HTML, which sees names only as plain old strings.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do this, but nothing with jquery.  Just other variations of substring, replace, etc.

Answer (score -2):

```
 $('input[name="<name-here>"]')
```